# Python script fails to run using a Cronjob but executes from browser

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

The python file begins to get executed but them, error I get is -

---

Time : 2018-12-26 13:00:01.751099
   Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/pull.py", line 13, in <module>
   df = pd.read_csv('Datasets/MC_Master.csv')
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
  return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)

File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__

File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source

**FileNotFoundError: File b'Datasets/MC_Master.csv' does not exist**
```

---

The file MC_Master.csv is contained within cgi-bin/Datasets

PS: it works perfectly using shebang command $ *python3 pull.py* while i am in the *cgi-bin directory*.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You must use absolute path for the dataset. Try changing Dataset/file.csv to /cgi-bin/Dataset/file.csv or whatever the absolute path is.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Much appreciated. As suggested, I have used absolute path.

Comment: What should be the file permissions for cronjob execution?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using relative path in your script, when you are working from `cgi-bin` directory, the relative paths are working fine but while running with cron, a program is executed with user's home directory as working directory. To overcome this problem, as @Gaurav mentioned, use absolute path in scripts, or just change current working directory within the program using `os.chdir('/path/to/cgi-bin')` before accessing the files.

Comment: do NOT use `os.chdir()` - this is brittle at best -, use absolute path.